# How to use Rhino.Mocks to evaluate class Properties (getters and setters)

Tags: c#-4.0, rhino-mocks, getter-setter

I'm studying how Rhino.Mocks works and trying to understand how can I set manually a value in a class Property.

I have seen a sample in internet where you have only desired Property as argument of Expect.Call(), instead of using a method.

```
MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository(); 
Person p = mocks.StrictMock<Person>();
Expect.Call(p.FirstName).Return("John");
```

Person is a class such as:

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

I always receive the error:

> Invalid call, the last call has been
>   used or no call has been made (make
>   sure that you are calling a virtual
>   (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).

Am I missing something? Is it possible to set manually class Properties and evaluate them to see if getters and setters are working fine?

Comment: Did you make sure that you are calling **virtual** property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with any mocking framework, Rhino Mocks can only mock interfaces or classes that defines virtual methods and properties.

That's because when implementing a class, Rhino creates a derived class from the one you specify, replacing every `virtual` (or `Overridable` in VB) method with a stub implementation that uses an interceptor to handle the call.

When you specify a non virtual method, Rhino can't create a wrapper.

That is also true tor `sealed` (`NonInheritable` in VB) classes.

So for your class to work, you should implement the property as such:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

This way Rhino can override the poperty accordingly.

Comment: @Darin: Thanks.. Didn't see the typo